# Logger configuration in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

Is there  a specific onfiguration for logger to print log.info() message  ?   I have action classes extended quatz class as shown below .  but the log is not printing out in log file - alfresco.log . I can see system.out.println in tomcat log .

please let me know if there are any configuration changes reuired in log4j.properties  ? I have kept all the config default didnt make any changes in log4j

following is screen shot of  java class

Comment: found your cross post in [Alfresco Hub](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/logger-configuration/m-p/296538#M17956). Please don't cross post and if you do reference the other post to let others know ...

Answer (score 0):

- Alfresco's documentation is well indexed by Google: [log4j.properties file](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-module-log4j.html)
- You need to overwriter the root loogging config
  `log4j.rootLogger=error`
  by enable the required log level for your package / class by
  `log4j.com.mycompany.mypackage.myclass=info`